# What is the difference between "threads" and "Samples" in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Since I am a new to Jmeter,I have a little confusion regarding the difference between "Threads" and "Samples" in the Jmeter.

For example
Sometimes we have set the "Number of thread" as "200" and run the test in jmeter . We have seen the  "samples" as "200" in the summary report.But sometimes for the same threads we are seeing  "samples" as "160" or  "samples" as "240"in the summary report.[Image shows how we have set the threads in jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ws5l.png)

Can any please explain the difference between threads and samples?Whether samples may differ from the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads and Samples are totally different.

- **Threads represent the number of virtual users.**
- **Samples represent the number of total requests made by users.**

So suppose if you have a test plan with 5 requests.

If you run it with 1 user   : you will have 1 thread and 5 samples.
If you run it with 10 users : you will have 10 threads and 50 samples.

Note, that number of threads or samples could vary because of machine/network/server limitations etc.

For example we ask JMeter to create 1000 threads but our machine is able to create only 100 threads at maximum (because of low CPU/ram)

Similarly, number of samples could be less/more because of network failure, test scenario etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recorded a workflow, and want to run with single user you set the number of Threads as 1.Threads are nothing but # users.

The Samplers are the individual requests. If you group the samplers using "Transaction Controller" by checking "Generate parent Sample" all samplers under that Transaction Controller is treated as Single.